# Defining a Differentiable Function in a Non-Pointwise Manner

Tags: calculus, definition, differential-topology

Is there a way to define a differentiable function in a non-pointwise manner? That is without defining function differentiable at a point first.

Just like we define a continuous function through open subsets.

As far as I recall there was something involving the chain rule and probably Leibniz rule, but I don't remember by now.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but here are some thoughts.

Differentiability is defined at a point, however, there are some concepts which relate differentiability to more global properties.  The first that come to my mind are the [Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) and [Lipschitz Continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).

The Fourier Transform of the derivative of a function at $\xi$ is the Fourier Transform of that function times $\xi$; that is, $\widehat{f'}(\xi)=2\pi i\xi\widehat{f}(\xi)$. In this way, the differentiability of a function is related to decay of its Fourier Transform. The smoother a function is, the faster its Fourier Transform decays near $\infty$.

The idea of Lipschitz Continuity relates a kind of uniform smoothness to the $L^\infty$ norm of the difference of a function and nearby translates.  That is, $\|f-T_hf\|_{L^\infty}\le C|h|$ where $T_hf(x)=f(x+h)$ is a translation operator. In this case, $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere and $\|f'\|_{L^\infty}\le C$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one:

*A function $f:\ I\to{\mathbb R}$ is continuously differentiable on the open interval $I$ iff there is a continuous function $L:\ I\times I\to{\mathbb R}$ such that*
$$f(y)-f(x)=L(x,y)\,(y-x)\qquad (x, y\in I)\ .$$
*Proof.* If $f\in C^1(I)$ then $$f(y)-f(x)=\int_x^y f'(t)\ dt=(y-x)\int_0^1 f'\bigl((1-\tau)x+\tau y\bigr)\ d\tau\ ;$$ therefore the function
$$L(x,y)\ :=\ \int_0^1 f'\bigl((1-\tau)x+\tau y\bigr)\ d\tau$$
has the required properties. Conversely, if there is such an $L$ then
$$f'(x)=\lim_{y\to x}{f(y)-f(x)\over y-x}=\lim_{y\to x}L(x,y)=L(x,x)\ ,$$
and the right side is continuous as a function of $x$.

This principle can be extended to the multivariable case.

Comment: This is certainly correct and if you use the "global" definition of continuity mentioned by the OP you get what is in some sense a "global" definition of (continuous) differentiability.  But doesn't this feel somewhat "cheap"?  It seems you have placed very thin wrapping paper around the usual definition of differentiability...